# Merging two PySpark DataFrame's gives unexpected results

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two **PySpark DataFrames** (NOT pandas):

```
df1 =

    +----------+--------------+-----------+---------+
    |pk        |num_id        |num_pk     |qty_users|
    +----------+--------------+-----------+---------+
    |  63479840|      12556940|     298620|       13|
    |  63480030|      12557110|     298620|        9|
    |  63835520|      12627890|     299750|        8|

df2 =

    +----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
    |pk2       |num_id2       |num_pk2    |qty_users2|
    +----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
    |  63479800|      11156940|     298620|       10 |
    |  63480030|      12557110|     298620|        1 |
    |  63835520|      12627890|     299750|        2 |
```

I want to join both DataFrames in order to get one DataFrame `df`:

```
    +----------+--------------+-----------+---------+
    |pk        |num_id        |num_pk     |total    |
    +----------+--------------+-----------+---------+
    |  63479840|      12556940|     298620|       13|
    |  63479800|      11156940|     298620|       10|
    |  63480030|      12557110|     298620|       10|
    |  63835520|      12627890|     299750|       10|
```

The only condition for merging is that I want to sum up the values of `qty_users` for those rows that have the same values of `< pk, num_id, num_pk >` in `df1` and `df2`. Just as I showed in the above example.

How can I do it?

**UPDATE:**

This is what I did:

```
newdf = df1.join(df2,(df1.pk==df2.pk2) & (df1.num_pk==df2.num_pk2) & (df1.num_id==df2.num_id2),'outer')

newdf = newdf.withColumn('total', sum(newdf[col] for col in ["qty_users","qty_users2"]))
```

But it gives me 9 columns instead of 4 columns. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer join will return all columns from both tables.Also,we got to fill null values in qty_users as sum will also return null.

Finally, we can select using coalsece function,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

newdf = df1.join(df2,(df1.pk==df2.pk2) & (df1.num_pk==df2.num_pk2) & (df1.num_id==df2.num_id2),'outer').fillna(0,subset=["qty_users","qty_users2"])

newdf = newdf.withColumn('total', sum(newdf[col] for col in ["qty_users","qty_users2"]))

newdf.select(*[F.coalesce(c1,c2).alias(c1) for c1,c2 in zip(df1.columns,df2.columns)][:-1]+['total']).show()

+--------+--------+------+-----+
|      pk|  num_id|num_pk|total|
+--------+--------+------+-----+
|63479840|12556940|298620|   13|
|63480030|12557110|298620|   10|
|63835520|12627890|299750|   10|
|63479800|11156940|298620|   10|
+--------+--------+------+-----+
```

Hope this helps.!

Comment: So, if there is any row in df1 that is not present in df2, it will still appear in newdf, right? The same for rows in df2. I want to have both common and non-common rows in newdf.

Comment: Yes it should. Check it for yourself and let me know if it has any issues.

Answer (score -1):

Does this output what you want?

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], as_index=False).groupby(['pk','num_id','num_pk'])['qty_users'].sum()
```

The merging of your 2 dataframes is achieved via `pd.concat([df1, df2], as_index=False)`

Finding the sum of the `qty_users` columns when all other columns are the same first requires grouping by those columns

```
groupby(['pk','num_id','num_pk'])
```

and then finding the grouped sum of `qty_users`

```
['qty_users'].sum()
```

Comment: I don't use pandas. I use PySpark.